# Which tools I need to use to deploy new servers?

Tags: installation, deployment, server, continuous-deployment

I don't know how to properly ask this question. So, I can't find any information in Google.
I need something which will help me to deploy new servers. Imagine if I have several app servers, several database servers, several storage servers. And I need to deploy new 10 servers (2 app, 4 database, 4 storage).
The first step is to install OS on all nodes. Then I need to install all necessary tools on nodes. Then I need to configure all necesary tools. These all steps take a lot of times. I want to find some tools which help deploy new nodes to take less time.
Also I need some monitoring tool which shows if a server is alive.

Comment: The answer depends to some extent on where your servers live. Are they in your own datacenter, a private cloud or a public cloud?

Comment: They are rent dedicated servers